# JVM crashes when trying to create a NewObject through JNI

Tags: c++, jvm, java-native-interface

I have a native process which communicates with a compiled scala code via JNI. Inside the native process there is a function that creates a Java object and returns it back to the java process. But sometimes that call cause a crash.

Below is the JVM stack for the crash. The odd thing is this is happening randomly. I can't think of anything which could cause this. I checked both the class and the method id for the constructor. Both of them are valid values at the time of crash.

I would highly appreciate if someone can give any clue to what might be happening here.

```
Stack: [0x00007fcd237ff000,0x00007fcd24000000],  sp=0x00007fcd23ff9ac0,  free space=8170k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x6ecd44]  jni_NewObjectV+0xd4
C  [JavaRequestHandler+0x64ff36]  _Jv_JNIEnv::NewObject(__jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+0x86

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 621  callback.CallbackHandler.onCall(IILjava/util/ArrayList;IJ)Lcallback/ArgNode; (0 bytes) @ 0x00007fcd3c385653 [0x00007fcd3c385600+0x53]
J 678 C2 callback.CallbackHandler.call(IILscala/collection/Seq;)Lcallback/ArgNode; (45 bytes) @ 0x00007fcd3c3bf2dc [0x00007fcd3c3bee00+0x4dc]
J 642 C1 common.NativeFunctions.GetTime(Ljava/lang/String;)D (28 bytes) @ 0x00007fcd3c3906ec [0x00007fcd3c390280+0x46c]
j  CheckTime.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+8
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Below is the struct that I keep all the IDs.

```
struct ArgumentNode
{
    jclass argNodeID;
    jmethodID constructorID;

};
```

At the initialization of the native process I call below code to load the IDs.

```
bool CallBackHandler::initScalaFields()
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    bool isAttached = Interpreter::getEnv(&env);
    _argnode = new ArgumentNode;
    _argnode->argNodeID = env->FindClass("callback/ScalaArgumentNode");
    if (_argnode->argNodeID == NULL)
    {
        logger().error("ERR: Can't load ScalaArgumentNode");
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
        return false;
    }

    _argnode->constructorID = env->GetMethodID(_argnode->argNodeID, "<init>", "()V");
    if (_argnode->constructorID == NULL)
    {
        logger().error("ERR: Can't load ScalaArgumentNode Constructor ID");
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This code causes the crash

```
jobject CallbackHandler::functionCallback(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint numberofargs)
{
    //This line causes the crash
    jobject nwsc_obj = env->NewObject(_argnode->argNodeID, _argnode->constructorID, NULL);

    //Some logic

    return nwsc_obj;
}
```

Comment: Most likely, `JNIEnv*` or `jclass` or some other `jobect` is incorrectly cached between calls. But it's hard to guess without seeing the code.

Comment: @apangin But the native function gets called many times before the crash. Java Env doesn't even through an error.  I don't delete the local reference of the object I create using the DeleteLocalRef. But I believe the local reference get deleted when the function scope ends.

Comment: *"native function gets called many times before the crash"* - this only supports the guess that the problem is caused by incorrectly cached references. They stay valid for some time until GC moves objects in the heap.

Comment: @apangin Anyway to clean the cache?

Comment: I mean there is a bug in your code that probably reuses references when it should not. I suggest you show some code that reproduces the problem, otherwise the question is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @apangin I will update the question with the code snippet.

Comment: @apangin sorry for delay. I updated the question with the code. Can you identify anything that I am doing wrong? If you need more code I can add.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is caching a jclass across JNI method calls. You explicitly cannot do that. You need a weak or global reference. See the JNI Reference.

Comment: @EJP Thank you. I'll try this and see. One small question does this need to be done only for the jclass? Hope what I am doing below is right. 
                                                                                                            
jclass localClass = env->FindClass("MyClass");
jclass globalClass = reinterpret_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(localClass));

Comment: The first guess was right - `jclass` reference is incorrectly reused. I'm closing the question as the duplicate of a similar problem. See the linked answer for details.

Comment: It also applies to `jobject`, as a glance at the documentation I referred you to would have shown, and as @apangin told you a week and a half ago.